# Why is .htaccess letting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-configuration

I am having a bit of an issue with .htaccess. I want to stop mod rewrite taking effect if the directory is secure, or any sub directory/file of secure. I have set up .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#skip next rule if url starts with secure/
RewriteRule ^/secure/(.*) - [L,S]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it isn't working? I can't just turn off mod rewrite because I need to use htpassword for the directory.

Answer (score 0):

In per-directory-context, the slash is appended to the end of the directory (leaving the part that rewriterule matches without a leading slash). [Your first rule will therefore never match.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) In this case I think you can simply have a negative condition using [`%{REQUEST_URI}`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secure/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```